# Как мне вывести canvas на задний фон

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

Использовал библиотеку канваса `particles.js`, все подключил, канвас идеально отображается. Вот только канвас занял всю страницу, закрыв доступ к заветным кнопкам на сайте.

```js
  

 particlesJS("particles-js", {
    particles: {
      number: { value: 101, density: { enable: true, value_area: 850 } },
      color: { value: "#ffffff" },
      shape: {
        type: "circle",
        stroke: { width: 0, color: "#000000" },
        polygon: { nb_sides: 3 },
        image: { src: "img/github.svg", width: 100, height: 100 }
      },
      opacity: {
        value: 1,
        random: false,
        anim: { enable: false, speed: 1, opacity_min: 0.1, sync: false }
      },
      size: {
        value: 1.5,
        random: true,
        anim: { enable: false, speed: 40, size_min: 0.1, sync: false }
      },
      line_linked: {
        enable: true,
        distance: 150,
        color: "#ffffff",
        opacity: 0.4,
        width: 1
      },
      move: {
        enable: true,
        speed: 6,
        direction: "none",
        random: false,
        straight: false,
        out_mode: "out",
        bounce: false,
        attract: { enable: false, rotateX: 600, rotateY: 1200 }
      }
    },
    interactivity: {
      detect_on: "canvas",
      events: {
        onhover: { enable: true, mode: "repulse" },
        onclick: { enable: false, mode: "push" },
        resize: true
      },
      modes: {
        grab: { distance: 400, line_linked: { opacity: 1 } },
        bubble: { distance: 400, size: 40, duration: 2, opacity: 8, speed: 3 },
        repulse: { distance: 70, duration: 0.4 },
        push: { particles_nb: 4 },
        remove: { particles_nb: 2 }
      }
    },
    retina_detect: true
  });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font: normal 75% Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
} /* ---- particles.js container ---- */
#particles-js {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="particles-js" ></div> 

 ##В коде страницы отображается так:
<div id="particles-js">
<canvas class="particles-js-canvas-el" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="1349" height="424"></canvas>
</div>  ##
```

Откуда появился новый `class="particles-js-canvas-el"` и как его поставить на фон

Comment: *Откуда появился новый class="particles-js-canvas-el" ?* - particles.js 1506 `canvas_el.className = pJS_canvas_class;`

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте указать валидный селектор `particlesJS("#particles-js", {})`, скорее всего библиотека не находит элемент и создает свой в конце страницы

Либо через `css` с указанием `z-index`

Answer (score 0):

Если particles.js, отработал и `canvas` отображается, и проблема просто в стилях.
То решить проблему перекрытия, наверняка, можно с помощью CSS.

Попробуйте поиграться со свойством `z-index` для элементов на странице. Оно как раз отвечает за порядок наложения элементов. Следует заметить что оно влияет только на элементы со свойством `position` установленным например в `absolute`, `fixed` или `relative`..

К сожалению я не вижу всей верстки. И трудно дать точный ответ.
Но возможно подойдет такая конструкция: `#particles-js { z-index: -1; ...}`.

Что касается элемента `<canvas class="particles-js-canvas-el" ...>/canvas>` то этот элемент создается библиотекой particles.js, и лучше не привязывать стили или скрипты к нему, можно считать его - закрытой внутренней реализацией данной библиотеки.